# Local Notification not show in simulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I create new project use
Plugin.LocalNotification version 10.0.2

Xamarin.Forms version 5.0.0.2515

this code in MainPage

```
 async void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var notification = new NotificationRequest
                {
                    NotificationId = 100,
                    Title = "Test",
                    Description = "Test Description",
                    ReturningData = "Dummy data", // Returning data when tapped on notification.
                    Schedule =
    {
        NotifyTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5) // Used for Scheduling local notification, if not specified notification will show immediately.
    }
                };
                await Plugin.LocalNotification.LocalNotificationCenter.Current.Show(notification);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
```

no exception found and no notification appears what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the examples of local notifications in Forms official documents. For iOS, before an app can send a notification to the user, the app must be registered with the system, and since notifications are intrusive to the user, the app must explicitly request permission before sending the notification.

You can refer to the following documents:

[Local notifications in Xamarin.Forms | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications)

[Asking Permission to Use Notifications | Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications?language=objc)

Comment: It come silent in background not show on the top of screen and on foreground not show any thing

Comment: Can you tell me what you have tried? Did you ask permission to use notifications? If you want notifications in the background, you need to [set up background tasks for your app.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app?language=objc).